# cisco vlan: can a trunk port talk to an access port under the same vlan?

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, bridging

Let's say we have a trunk port A with native vlan 2, access port B with vlan 2.

When A send an untagged frame to B, can B receive it?

When A send a tagged frame with vlan id 2 to B, can B receive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's say we have a trunk port A with native vlan 2, access port B with vlan 2.
>
> When A send an untagged frame to B, can B receive it?

If the trunk port is not configured with `vlan dot1q tag native`, then yes B can receive it, because A sees all untagged frames in the native vlan (vlan2)

> When A send a tagged frame with vlan id 2 to B, can B receive it?

If you use [native vlan tagging](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2217944)... the command is `vlan dot1q tag native`.  Note that this tags all frames, and I think it now would ignore untagged frames.